# Azure DataFactory. Convert date format on import to SQL DB

Tags: sql-server, csv, datetime, azure, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Datafactory to import a number of CSV files that I have into an Azure SQL DB.  I have a problem related to the date fields in the database which are currently set as `DATE` (I have also tried 'DATETIME').

The date format in the CSV look like

```
20160700000000
```

and when I try and map the CSV headings to DB rows in Azure Datafactory it tells me they are incompatible.

Do I need to modify the type in the DB to something other than DATE/DATETIME or is there something I can do in the import pipeline within Datafactory?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if this would work, look at "Type conversion sample" section from here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-sql-connector/ you may be able to specify the datetime format on your csv dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You've got three options:

1. Fix the data source's export to use something normative (and I don't see any day in your presumably accurate sample of the data).
2. Massage the column with a hive job.
3. Utilize a stored procedure to fix the date column for inserting.

I'm assuming you're doing a straight table mapped dataset.  If you have no control over the source data then you'll have to get creative.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what the date time of the value "20160700000000". If it means "7/1/2016 12:00:00 AM", you could set the source structure like the followings to parse such value as dateTime:

"structure":[
                { "name": "lastlogindate", "type": "Datetime", **"format": "yyyyMM00000000"**}]

Refer to this link for more details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-sql-connector/#specifying-structure-definition-for-rectangular-datasets